# Draftjs mention plugin with browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, mention, draft-js-plugins

I tried to get the mention plugin in draft-js get working with Browserify.
This is because of the fact that our application is build with Browserify.

It's about this plugin: https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/mention

In the examples they are using Webpack, and they use imports.

I use require. So an example of my code is:

```
var React       = require('react'),
    Draft       = require('draft-js'),
    Immutable   = require('immutable'),
    Editor      = require('draft-js-plugins-editor'),
    Mention     = require('draft-js-mention-plugin');

var mentionPlugin = Mention.createMentionPlugin();
var MentionSuggestions = mentionPlugin.MentionSuggestions;
var plugins = [mentionPlugin];

var Editor = React.createClass({
    // Code
});
```

I don't use ES6 notation. 
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No I didn't. But `Mention.createMentionPlugin()` must be `Mention.default()` I think

Answer (score 0):

That plugin's default export is the actual create-function, so it should be:

```
var createMentionPlugin = require('draft-js-mention-plugin');

var mentionPlugin = createMentionPlugin();
var MentionSuggestions = mentionPlugin.MentionSuggestions;
var plugins = [mentionPlugin];
```